# How to marshal a string to a null terminated ascii or utf8 IntPtr

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

How do I marshal a .net string to a null terminated ascii or utf8 IntPtr. For use on linux when interloping to a c lib.

I'm trying to call a c function with signiture like the following:

```
void my_function(const char* str)
```

My c# definition is as follows:

```
[DllImport("mylib.so)]
public static extern void my_function(IntPtr str);
```

I'm using an IntPtr for the interop because the native code holds onto the string longer than the duration of the function call. So I need to be able to marshal/pin it myself.

Things I've considered:

- Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni (seems to do 16 bit characters)
- Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi (ansi is for windows I think)
- Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUTF8 (says it uses the Com allocator, which seems wrong as this is not for com interop)
- Marshal.StringToBSTR (says it's for com interop)
- Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto (not sure about this one, says it converts to ansi if required which isn't what I want, also no details on how it decides or what it converts to if it doesn't do ansi)

There is also the option of converting to a ascii or utf8 byte array and then marshalling the resulting array (with a null terminator on the end) but this seem like overkill, especially if one of the string marshalling options does the correct thing.

Comment: There is no method. You need to create and free it yourself. I would give you a code example but I am sure you know how to achieve it

Comment: Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUTF8 is fine. You'll need to deallocate it after the call returns, as per the docs.

Comment: It's open source. Just have a look at it: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c3c768b4c36012661baf46a717649ae04d642c90/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs#L756 and for unix: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c3c768b4c36012661baf46a717649ae04d642c90/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.Unix.cs#L107 so StringToCoTaskMemUTF8  is fine, AllocCoTaskMem and AllocHGlobal are the same and it's not COM allocator, just platform allocator.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`. This is the ANSI version of the `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` function. The ANSI version deals with strings which use `char` as the underlying character type, whereas the Unicode version deals with wide strings which use `wchar_t` as the underlying character type. The function names were written [with Win32-colored glasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15458564).

From your perspective, you have an unmanaged C routine that expects a C-style string, using `char` as the underlying character type, so that matches with `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`.

`Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` allocates unmanaged memory for the string, which you can then pass to the C code. Because the memory is allocated on the unmanaged heap, GC pinning is not necessary. Once the C code is done, you will need to free the memory by calling `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

Comment: Don't think this is right. That api very likely wants UTF8 text. I think my comment above is accurate.